# 5 linear equations in 5 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

I need an example of 5 linearly independent equations with 5 variables. How can I write such a equation set. As an example:

```
                      0   0    0    0   1   |   -4
                      0   0    1   -1   0   |    3
                      1   0    0    0   1   |    2
                      0   7   -8    0   0   |  -14
                      2   0    0    0   0   |    2
```

But this is wrong. I need to build a correct one.

Comment: I don't get it. What's wrong with the above system?

Comment: @user1551 - row 1 + 0.5 row 5 =row 3

Comment: @Belgi Oh I see. The OP wants a full rank coefficient matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose any $\hat{x}_{1} , \ldots , \hat{x}_{5}$, and use the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x}_{1} \\
\hat{x}_{2} \\
\hat{x}_{3} \\
\hat{x}_{4} \\
\hat{x}_{5} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If you want something that is less obvious, you can start multiplying the rows by nonzero constants:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \hat{x}_{1} \\
\hat{x}_{2} \\
\hat{x}_{3} \\
\hat{x}_{4} \\
\hat{x}_{5} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(in this example, we multiply the first row by $2$), or adding multiples of one row to another row:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \hat{x}_{1} \\
\hat{x}_{2} \\
\hat{x}_{3} - 3 \hat{x}_{5} \\
\hat{x}_{4} \\
\hat{x}_{5} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(in this example, we add $-3$ times the fifth row to the third row).

Comment: This steps will not create linearly dependent equations, right? Because I want all equations to be linearly independent. Sorry for asking too much.

Comment: Suppose we use the steps above to generate a system. Then, we can solve the system using Gaussian elimination. But this is just doing the steps above in reverse! Therefore, the equations remain linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Begin with a 5x5 **random** matrix, with **positive** diagonal. For example,
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-3&2&4\\
5&6&7&8&-9\\
1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
2&-3&2&-3&4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then compute the **absolute** row sums (i.e. sum up the absolute values of the entries in each row):
\begin{align}
1+0+3+2+4=10\\
5+6+7+8+9=35\\
1+1+1+1+1=5\\
0+0+0+1+0=1\\
2+3+2+3+4=14.
\end{align}
Add these row sums to the diagonal of $A$:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1+10&0&-3&2&4\\
5&6+35&7&8&-9\\
1&1&1+5&1&1\\
0&0&0&1+1&0\\
2&-3&2&-3&4+14
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The rows of $A$ are then linearly independent. If you want to make $A$ looks more random, further scramble the rows or columns of $A$. Then form a random but nice looking solution vector $x$ (so that you may control the look of the solution). Compute $b=Ax$ and let the coefficients of $b$ be the numbers on the RHS of the equations. The resulting system will always have a unique solution, which is your nice $x$.

Comment: Why does this work ?

Comment: @Belgi Because $A$ will then be strictly diagonally dominant. Hence by Gershgorin disc theorem, $0$ can never be an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Write in matrix form this system: $x_1=1,...,x_5=5$

Comment: ... or if you want something slightly less trivial, take an upper triangular system with nonzero diagonal elements.

Comment: Although technically correct, I hesitate to call these "unknowns."

Comment: @NicolásKim - you can always mess it up with elementary row operations. I saw no need to make it complicated, I would of written this on an exam since clearly $I$ is invertible so this saves some work in arguing why the example is good

Comment: @RobertIsrael - thats true, but the OP may not understand why does this work at this stage...

Comment: this has no solution, I am looking for one with a unique solution

Comment: @Ersin - Why no solution ?

Comment: @Belgi , maybe I have lack of info about this subject. But can you please identify the solution of this. I found from eq1 that x5=-4. from eq3, x1=6 but from eq5, x1=1. What am I missing?

Comment: @Ersin - from eq 1 $x_1=1$, from the second: $x_2=2$,...from the fifth $x_5=5$

Comment: First eq : x5=-4
Second eq: x3-x4=3
Third eq: x1+x5=2 and go on. Right?

Comment: @NicolásKim it is better to call them as variables i think.